# How is it possible to change the position of an object consisted of points floating around a center in Three Js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, shader, webgl

So I have made this galaxy object consisted of points floating around its center

```
const parameters = {}

parameters.count = 4500
parameters.size = 0.005
parameters.radius = 0.7
parameters.branches = 4
parameters.spin = 1
parameters.randomness = 0.1
parameters.randomnessPower = 5
parameters.insideColor = '#d42b2b'
parameters.outsideColor = '#14be4c'

let galaxyGeometry = null
let galaxyMaterial = null
let galaxyPoints = null

const generateGalaxy = () => 
{   
    //DESTROY STUFF
    if(galaxyPoints !== null)
    {
        galaxyGeometry.dispose()
        galaxyMaterial.dispose()
        scene.remove(galaxyPoints)
    }

    //GALAXY GEOM AND PARTICLES
    galaxyGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry()

    const positions = new Float32Array(parameters.count * 3)
    const randomness = new Float32Array(parameters.count * 3)
    const galaxyColors = new Float32Array(parameters.count * 3)
    const galaxyScales = new Float32Array(parameters.count * 1)

    const colorInside = new THREE.Color(parameters.insideColor)
    const colorOutside = new THREE.Color(parameters.outsideColor)

    for(let i = 0; i < parameters.count; i++)
    {
        const i3 = i * 3
        //POSITION
        const radius = Math.random() * parameters.radius
        
        const branchAngle = (i % parameters.branches) / parameters.branches * Math.PI * 2
        
        const randomX = Math.pow(Math.random(), parameters.randomnessPower) * (Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1: -1) * parameters.randomness * radius
        const randomY = Math.pow(Math.random(), parameters.randomnessPower) * (Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1: -1) * parameters.randomness * radius
        const randomZ = Math.pow(Math.random(), parameters.randomnessPower) * (Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1: -1) * parameters.randomness * radius

        positions[i3    ] = Math.cos(branchAngle) * radius
        positions[i3 + 1] = 0
        positions[i3 + 2] = Math.sin(branchAngle) * radius
    
        randomness[i3    ] = randomX
        randomness[i3 + 1] = randomY
        randomness[i3 + 2] = randomZ

        //COLORS
        // Color
        const mixedColor = colorInside.clone()
        mixedColor.lerp(colorOutside, radius / parameters.radius)

        galaxyColors[i3    ] = mixedColor.r
        galaxyColors[i3 + 1] = mixedColor.g
        galaxyColors[i3 + 2] = mixedColor.b

        // Scale
        galaxyScales[i] = Math.random()
    }

    galaxyGeometry.setAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(positions, 3))
    galaxyGeometry.setAttribute('aRandomness', new THREE.BufferAttribute(randomness, 3))
    galaxyGeometry.setAttribute('color', new THREE.BufferAttribute(galaxyColors, 3))
    galaxyGeometry.setAttribute('aScale', new THREE.BufferAttribute(galaxyColors, 3))

    //GALAXY PARTICLE MATERIALS
    galaxyMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
        depthWrite: false,
        blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
        vertexColors: true,
        uniforms:
        {   
            vAlpha: { value: 1.0 },
            uTime: { value: 0 },
            uSize: { value: 40 * renderer.getPixelRatio() }
        },
        vertexShader: galaxyVertex,
        fragmentShader: galaxyFragment,
    })
    if(galaxyMaterial.uniforms.vAlpha.value !== 1.0)
    {
        galaxyGeometry.dispose()
        galaxyMaterial.dispose()
        scene.remove(galaxyPoints)
    }
    //GALAXY MESH
    galaxyPoints = new THREE.Points(galaxyGeometry, galaxyMaterial)
    console.log(galaxyPoints.position)
    scene.add(galaxyPoints)
}
```

along with its vertex

```
uniform float uTime;
 uniform float uSize;

 attribute vec3 aRandomness;
 attribute float aScale;

varying vec3 vColor;

void main()
{
    //POSITION
    vec4 modelPosition = modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
                
    // Rotate
    float angle = atan(modelPosition.x, modelPosition.z);
    float distanceToCenter = length(modelPosition.xz);
    float angleOffset = (1.0 / distanceToCenter) * uTime * 3.0;
    angle += angleOffset;
    modelPosition.x = cos(angle) * distanceToCenter;
    modelPosition.y = sin(angle) * distanceToCenter;

    // Randomness
    modelPosition.xyz += aRandomness;

    vec4 viewPosition = viewMatrix * modelPosition;
    vec4 projectedPosition = projectionMatrix * viewPosition;
    gl_Position = projectedPosition;

    //SIZE
    gl_PointSize = uSize * aScale;
    gl_PointSize *= (1.0 / - viewPosition.z);

    //COLOR
    vColor = color;
}
```

and fragment shader

```
varying vec3 vColor;
uniform float vAlpha;

void main()
{
    //LIGHT PATTERN
    float strength = distance(gl_PointCoord, vec2(0.5));
    strength = 1.0 - strength;
    strength = pow(strength, 8.0);

    //FINAL COLOR
    vec3 color = mix(vec3(0.0), vColor, strength);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color, vAlpha);
}
```

. So my question here is this.How is it possible to move the object around the scene without changing its original look (galaxy/portal like). As I am new to Three js the only way I've known to move an object around is picking up the mesh and setting its position to whatever needed. The problem I'm having right now though is that the points are moving around a central point. When I try to move the mesh around the whole galaxy is breaking up. What is the correct approach here in order to move the whole galaxy thing, let's say by 2.0 in the x , y or z axis? I would really appreciate an explanation to why this is happening as well. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Would you be able to convert the code you posted into a run-able snippet? It would be much easier to observe what's happening if we can run the whole system.

Comment: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/orestis-tserkanos/pen/abyYrMa) Sorry for being late to give a response. I've been losing brain cells trying to figure it out, to no particular result though :/ . I hope the codepen works. @TheJim01

Comment: @TheJim01 As you can see in the Codepen, the whole "vortex" thingy is in the middle of the screen. What I wanna do is try and move it up and down, left or right, like a normal object with ThreeJs. With just Meshes it's pretty easy, I just set a position -e.g mesh.position.set(3, 3, 3) - and everything works fine. But due to the fact that my galaxyobject is made with Points, another approach must be made. Most probably have to do with math, which I'm really bad at to be honest.